# Angular does not update value to View when change in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this in view

```
<span [ngStyle]="{width: optionActiveWindowSize}" class="option-active-window"></span>

<ng-container *ngFor="let op of options; let i = index">
   <div [ngClass]="{active: i === activeIndex"}></div>
</ng-container>
```

Ts Code

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const activeOption = 
    this.horizontalOptionRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('active');
    this.optionActiveWindowSize = activeOption[0].offsetWidth + 'px';
}
```

Value of optionActiveWindowSize does not change in the DOM after it was changed in afterViewInit.
Can you please tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?
Span doesn't have width property

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of problems.

1. Make sure, **optionActiveWindowSize** has a string value with `px` defined in the end like,

   eg. `optionActiveWindowSize = '20px'`. Then,

   ```
   [ngStyle]="{width: optionActiveWindowSize}"
   ```

   should work.
2. I assume,  **optionActiveWindowSize** has a numeric value like `optionActiveWindowSize = 20`, then you should change it as,

   ```
    [ngStyle]="{ 'width.px': optionActiveWindowSize}"
   ```

**OR**

```
     [style.width.px]="optionActiveWindowSize"
```

Hope, this will help !

**NOTE**: *Forgot to mention as @M Fuat NUROGLU mentioned, `span` doesn't have `width` prop. So, you may want to change it to `div`*.

Comment: Maybe that's because of  `span` tag. did you try to change it to `div` ?

Comment: try to reproduce here if possible : https://stackblitz.com/edit/iframe-example-t5pjyf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You are binding styles after those styles are already rendered.

no event loop there to track it.

see detailed info from here : https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

If you want to imply those styles before your page is rendered.

use this :

```
  const activeOption = 
    this.horizontalOptionRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('active');
    this.optionActiveWindowSize = activeOption[0].offsetWidth + 'px';
```

In your

```
ngOnInit()
```

method.

Comment: If I put these code in ngOnInit(), the .active Element has not been grenerated. Therefore, activeOption will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. It's because changeDetection is ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```